# Как переконфигурить OAuth2Config

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth2

Есть конфигурация

```
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().
                withClient(Clients.WEB.getValue()).
                authorizedGrantTypes(GrantType.PASSWORD.getValue()).
                autoApprove(true).
                scopes(Scope.WEB.getValue()).
                accessTokenValiditySeconds(300);
    }
}
```

Нужно иметь возможность по вызову ендпоинта сетать новое значение `accessTokenValiditySeconds` (там, где в начале 300). Собственно, как сделать обновление ?

Comment: Ну... По идее это значение должно в БД лежать и менять его надо там. Если не хотите БД, а хотите, чтобы оно было только в оперативке, то создайте сервис, в него поместите переменную для хранения числа секунд и дайте методы для set/get этого значения. Соответственно в конфиге берите из сервиса и сетайте в сервис в контроллере. Однако не факт, что изменения будут подхватываться. Будут или нет - смотрите в исходниках спринга. Если хранить значение в БД - то точно подхватываются, я проверял.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я имею в виду как сделать так, чтобы спринг подхватил новое значение

Comment: Я выше предложил способ. Правда не знаю, сработает или нет. Если вы это пробовали и это не работает - напишите об этом в вопросе)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как должна быть связана ваша "БД" и конфиг спринга ? Или вы про сервис ?

Comment: Вариант с БД сложный, очень много надо всякого сделать чтобы обхяснить спрингу где что лежит и как этим пользоваться. Сейчас я не готов ответ про это писать. Попробуйте вариант без БД. Например просто переменную, в которую контроллер будет при вызове его метода что-то писать, а конфиг будет оттуда читать. Вдруг это сработает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб метод configure отрабатывает на ините, читает 300 и все. дальше нужно либо как-то руками дернуть configure еще раз или как-то еще

Comment: Угу... Бегло погуглил, вроде бы, действительно, никак не выйдет кроме как с БД. Попробуйте вот эту статью для реализации через БД: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-dynamic-client-registration